How to create line topology from-node to-node table fields?
We are looking for a way to create line topology from-node and to-node attribute fields on a shape file as shown below.  We know that ArcHydroTools GenerateFNodeTNode can do it, but want to avoid using ArcGIS and use open source software, such as QGIS, etc.
Example:


That is the ArcInfo coverage topology format - it is very old https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/coverages/coverage-topology.htm it can be opened (limited) in QGIS but the lost of attribution is likely see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211413/276
